# Find all anchors except first

Tags: jquery

```
   $(".virtual-image").click(function(){
       var first_anchor = $(this).find('a:first');
       var data_title = first_anchor.attr('data-lightbox');
       first_anchor.removeAttr('data-lightbox');
       $(this).find('a').attr('data-lightbox',data_title);
   });
```

I want to select all anchors except the first. I have tried `:not` selector.

Answer (score 0):

use **[gt](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)** selector:

```
$(this).find('a:gt(0)').attr('data-lightbox',data_title);
```

or

```
$(this).find('a:not(:first)').attr('data-lightbox',data_title);
```

or

```
$(this).find('a:not(:eq(0))').attr('data-lightbox',data_title);
```

Answer (score 0):

use [.slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/)

```
$(this).find('a').slice(1).attr('data-lightbox',data_title);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your code then swap the last two lines like,

```
$(this).find('a').attr('data-lightbox',data_title);//first add attr to all anchors
first_anchor.removeAttr('data-lightbox');// now remove attr
```

And if not, then you can use @Arun or @Milind answer.

Comment: the purpose of this is that i am using lightbox plugin of jquery and i want that in light box i should exclude the first image in which user is clicking. when i am using not select or your code my lightbox is not working.